# load static files not working even after referencing

Tags: python, django, backend

I am trying to modify a bootstrap made webpage for my project the thing is the statis files (collectively assets) are put inside the folder so the project name is Portfolio
then the static file is in tha path `/static/Portfolio/static/` inside that static folder we get the `/assests` folder - > `Portfolio/static/Portfolio/static/assets` like this now i tried to do the {% load static %} method in my index.html page few of the css got applied

here is the director

```
.
├── css
│   └── style.css
├── img
│   ├── apple-touch-icon.png
│   ├── favicon.png
│   ├── hero-bg.jpg
│   ├── portfolio
│   ├── profile-img.jpg
│   └── testimonials
├── js
│   └── main.js
├── scss
│   └── Readme.txt
└── vendor
    ├── aos
    ├── bootstrap
    ├── bootstrap-icons
    ├── boxicons
    ├── glightbox
    ├── isotope-layout
    ├── php-email-form
    ├── purecounter
    ├── swiper
    ├── typed.js
    └── waypoints
```

now here this is my header of my .HTML file

```html
{% load static %}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" name="viewport">

  <title>Siddharth D</title>
  <meta content="" name="description">
  <meta content="" name="keywords">

  <!-- Favicons -->
  <link href= " {% static 'assets/img/favicon.png' %}" rel="icon">
  <link href= " {% static 'assets/img/apple-touch-icon.png' %}" rel="apple-touch-icon">

  <!-- Google Fonts -->
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,300i,400,400i,600,600i,700,700i|Raleway:300,300i,400,400i,500,500i,600,600i,700,700i|Poppins:300,300i,400,400i,500,500i,600,600i,700,700i" rel="stylesheet">

  <!-- Vendor CSS Files -->
  <link href="{% static 'assets/vendor/aos/aos.css' %}">
  <link href="{% static 'assets/vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css' %}">
  <link href="{% static 'assets/vendor/bootstrap-icons/bootstrap-icons.css' %}">
  <link href="{% static 'assets/vendor/boxicons/css/boxicons.min.css' %}">
  <link href="{% static 'assets/vendor/glightbox/css/glightbox.min.css' %}">
  <link href="{% static 'assets/vendor/swiper/swiper-bundle.min.css' %}">

  <!-- Template Main CSS File -->
  <link href= "{% static 'assets/css/style.css'%}" rel="stylesheet">

  <!-- other static files -->
  <link href = "{% static 'assets/css/style.css' %}">
  <link href = "{% static 'assets/img/' %}">
  <link href = "{% static 'assets/img/portfolio' %}">
  <link href = "{% static 'assets/img/testimonials' %}">
```

as you can see here i have loaded all the static files and now when i reference it the output in the screen as soon i load is is this

```
[25/Jul/2023 10:25:43] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 33179
Not Found: /assets/vendor/purecounter/purecounter_vanilla.js
Not Found: /assets/vendor/aos/aos.js
[25/Jul/2023 10:25:43] "GET /assets/vendor/purecounter/purecounter_vanilla.js HTTP/1.1" 404 2337
[25/Jul/2023 10:25:43] "GET /assets/vendor/aos/aos.js HTTP/1.1" 404 2265
```

i have look upon the docs but not sure if there is more to be done am i supposed to do the hard coded way of {% load static ... } way for every single import is there any other way to reference everything link this the front end has lots of references is the a way around it or i am missing some point here i have read the docs but according to docs the referencing was done all the time is that the only way ?

[image]

some part of the css got loaded but the js is not getting loaded

it will be really helpfull if someone helps me solve this problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is that some of the references are incorrect

they should be like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'vendor/aos/aos.css' %}">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css' %}">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'vendor/bootstrap-icons/bootstrap-icons.css' %}">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'vendor/boxicons/css/boxicons.min.css' %}">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'vendor/glightbox/css/glightbox.min.css' %}">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'vendor/swiper/swiper-bundle.min.css' %}">
```

as you can see I have removed `assets/` from your `href` attributes because django's `{% static %}` template tag already includes the correct path to your static files and for other static files like  `img` you shouldn't use `<link>` tag for them instead use the `<img>` tags:

for example:

```
<img src="{% static 'img/something.png' %}" alt="Your Alt Text">
```

I hope this helps you.

Comment: thanks for solving the issue btw one more think i have already done ```{% load static %}``` then why should i mention is everytime i am importing smtng its already loaded right ?

Comment: {% load static %} enables the use of the {% static %} template tag to generate urls for static files like css, javascript, images and etc.